# ListView Adapter image loading wrong position

Tags: android, listview, adapter

This is very strange, when i scroll slow or medium everything is okay, but then i scroll really fast, sometimes (1/5) pictures are loaded in wrong position.

```
View mView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_suggested_user, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.circleImage = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.circle_image);
        holder.fullName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_suggested_fullname);
        holder.img1 = (SmartImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_suggested_img1);


        mView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        mView = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
    }


    final SuggestedUsersModel item = (SuggestedUsersModel) getItem(position);
    holder.fullName.setText(mList.get(position).getFullname());

    if (item.getProfilepictureurl() != null) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getProfilepictureurl().replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact)
                .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .into(holder.circleImage);
    } else {
        holder.circleImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact);
    }

        String type = item.getPosts().get(0).getMediatype();
        //For Image 1
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
            holder.img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.text_post_background);
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
            if (item.getPosts().get(0).getUri() != null) {

                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(item.getPosts().get(0).getUri().replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact)
                        .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .into(holder.img1);
            } else {
                holder.img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact);
            }
        } else {
            if (item.getPosts().get(0).getThumbnailuri() != null) {
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(item.getPosts().get(0).getThumbnailuri().replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact)
                        .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .into(holder.img1);
            } else {
                holder.img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact);
            }
        }
```

I am using Picasso , but i tried almost everything and result is the same. 
I already know how listview work and all that reuse for item, but this i cannot explain why is happening.

Please give me some ideas and solutions. 
Thanks

**UPDATE 1: I added button, and i change text on click, so here is happening again the same (when scrolling button gets mixed up on other position) , so i is NOT library for loading pictures. Can someone please help.**

Comment: Do you really need `View mView;`?

Comment: I solved this problem using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/2389078) project and since then suggesting everyone else to do same. This might help you also.

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser, not really but i tried without also..

Comment: @VishwasSharma, i am not in position to choose what to use, but i don't thing library is causing the problem coz i already tried few.

Comment: reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20311040/2389078) answer should help you to understand why your images get shuffled. This is a very long research after which I chose to use the library that I gave you the link for, above.

Comment: @Vishwas Sharma, so i guess you want to tell that library i am using is not taking care of this?

Comment: I have not seen the code of library that you are using, so I can't tell that this is really the reason. But I wanted to tell you, that, this is one of the main issue which cause the scrolling of images in `listview`. You might wanna check your library code or make corrections, if you can to fix this issue, if it is there in your library code.

Comment: @VishwasSharma, can you please look the update. Any idea? :/

Comment: Update your code in question. Which has new button code.

Comment: did you notified adapter after changing text on button? Problem with adapter is we don't know how its `getView` method works exactly. Do some research on `getView` method of `adapter` and you'll get to know why images and text on buttons is changing.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7739006/2389078) answer carefully over and over again to understand why text and images are changing. Phew, took me a while to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `if-else` condition for `convertView`.

Just put,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_suggested_user, parent, false);
holder = new ViewHolder();

holder.circleImage = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.circle_image);
holder.fullName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_suggested_fullname);
holder.img1 = (SmartImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_suggested_img1);
```

Let me know what happen..

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347505/strange-behaviour-in-android-listview-when-loading-images-with-asynctask/22347703#22347703

Comment: this solves the problem but scrolling is really really bad. Is there any other way to fix this and reuse 'convertView'

Comment: Scrolling of List is depends on your Image Loader.